# How to remove first and last special character of string in groovy language

Tags: groovy

```
String s ="[ABC_JJBB_DD]";
```

I'm getting string value from application data, how could I remove special character [ and ] in the string in groovy. Using

```
s.removeAll('[','']
```

Comment: `s.substring(1, s.length()-1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it the java route, as Aniket says:

```
s.substring(1, s.length()-1)
```

Or you can take the Groovy route of:

```
s[1..-2]
```

But you'd need to ensure `s` is longer than 1 char, with both of these, or else you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

If you don't want to check, you can do esoteric things like

```
s.drop(1).reverse().drop(1).reverse()
```

Which will work, but will be slower

Or, if you just want to remove all `[` and `]`, you could do

```
s.replaceAll(~/[\[\]]/, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Groovy 3 you can use `takeBetween`, that has beside other arguments one for start and end string.  E.g.

```
groovy:000> "[ABC_JJBB_DD]".takeBetween("[","]")
===> ABC_JJBB_DD
```

Comment: Ooooh, that's nice!

Comment: takebetween is cool. Can we have takebetween and  tokenize(_) in a single statement?

Comment: you can do `"[1] [2]".tokenize()*.takeBetween("[","]")`