# Remove first and last character Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a variable that looks like this :

```
[KEY-1]
```

I would like to remove the brackets. The brackets are always at the beginning and at the end. I want only the output

```
KEY-1
```

How can I make this happen in groovy thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove first and last special character of string in groovy language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735713/how-to-remove-first-and-last-special-character-of-string-in-groovy-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "-" operator for this

```
def myVar = '[KEY-1]'
myVar = myVar - '[' - ']'
assert myVar == 'KEY-1'
```

If your variable may contain another [ or ], you can use indexes for this purpose, as you mentioned you want to remove the beginning / end of the variable:

```
def myVar = '[KEY-1]'
myVar = myVar[1..myVar.size()-2]
assert myVar == 'KEY-1'
```

Comment: `myVar[1..myVar.size()-2]` can be simplified to `myVar[1..-2]`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
def var = '[foobar]'
def clean = var.toList().init().tail().join()
println clean
```

prints `foobar`. `init` gives you all characters except the last and `tail` gives you all characters except the first.